# Android scroll view

Tags: android, scroll, scrollbar

How to implement **scroll and scroll bar** in an android app?
I am new to android development suggest some websites other than android developers website to quickly learn.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Search in youtube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple, open your Android Studio, create new project (blank project). Then in `res/layout/activity_main.xml` replace with this code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test1" />
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test2" />
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test3" />
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test4" />
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .

         <!-- something you want to display -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

For learning android I suggest this website, it has a lot of clean and clear examples for you to try (it's old but for me it's good for beginner):

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/index.htm

And again Google is your best friend.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of a vertical scroll view:

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"/>

        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And a horizontal scroll view:

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"/>

        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a Simple task, you can achieve this by using a `ScrollView`. Put the `Layout` in Side a `ScrollView` and you are ready to go. One thing `ScrollView` can contain only one ChildView.

Example :

```
<ScrollView
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        ....>
        .
        .
        .
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```